# Change Magento 2 PHP version in SSH

Tags: php, upgrade, dependency, ssh, php-7.4

I'm currently trying to upgrade Magento 2.3.4 CE, to 2.4.0 CE. However I was constantly getting **"Component Dependency"** errors.

I then tried to upgrade in SSH but got the following error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I have changed the PHP version in Plesk to 7.4.10 but when I try to upgrade Magento I reveive the same error and using the command `php -v` gives the following error:

```
PHP 7.1.33-17+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2020 14:47:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33-17+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Can anyone tell me how to change the PHP version in SSH please?

Comment: I've tried it, thanks. I'm afraid it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try using php73 <command> instead of php <command> than

Answer (score 0):

You can run  `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and then an interactive window will open and you will be able to select the installed php versions, or you can simple do `sudo a2enmod php7.4` and then run `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, we use a Plesk control panel and cannot run sudo commands.

Comment: Did you have a look at the docs in Plesk, there is an explanation on how to change the php version?